# Google App Mail merge - child file sent without fields modified

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am building a simple Google App Script that sends an e-mail every month with a file attached.

The file is updated with :
-the first day of the current month
-the last day of the current month
-the name of the month

All document creation and fields modification works well (I see the gdoc with modified fields few seconds after the script is launched).

The problem is that I receive an e-mail WITHOUT the modified fields in the attachment.

Does anyone knows WHY THE CHILD DOCUMENT IS MODIFIED WELL, BUT THE PDF VERSION ATTACHED TO THE EMAIL HASN'T ITS FIELDS MODIFIED ?

Thank you !

```js
function myFunction() {
 
//DEALS WITH DATES
  //Create a date
  var today = new Date();
  
  //Create a variable that will take month's values
  var Mois = ["Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Decembre"];   
  
  //Get the current month
  var MoisNum = today.getMonth()+1;
  var TextMois = Mois[MoisNum-1];
  
  //Get the number of first day of the month, and last day of the month
  var Jour = today.getDate();
  var NombreJourMois = ["31", "28", "31","30","31","30","31","31","30","31","30","31"];
  var DernierJourMois = NombreJourMois[MoisNum-1];
  
  //Get the current year
  var Annee = today.getYear();
  
  //Sets two variable with the date of the first day of the month and last day of the month
  var DateDebutMois = 01+'/'+MoisNum+'/'+Annee;
  var DateFinMois = DernierJourMois+'/'+MoisNum+'/'+Annee;
 
  
  
//CREATE A COPY OF THE PARENT FILE AND PUT IT IN THE RIGHT FOLDER  
  //Dossier de destination et fichier template
  var DossierSource = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B0mCpRQd5BQidmQ2MGl4em9MRzA');
  var DossierCible = DriveApp.getFolderById("13pril4REhDrITljX523z7LdQgVpOcazU");
  var FichierSource = DriveApp.getFileById('109_Kuoxjh-C56MYeFhyyP-PhYJirCD5OVhuce0v7osI');
  
  //Create a copy of the document and put it in the above folder
  var Enfant = FichierSource.makeCopy();
  DossierCible.addFile(Enfant);
  DossierSource.removeFile(Enfant);
 
  
//MODIFY CHILD DOCUMENT WITH THE PROPER DATES AND RENAME IT  
  //Get the body of the child document
  var BodyEnfant = DocumentApp.openById(Enfant.getId()).getBody();
  
  //Replace date fields of the body by the right dates, and changes the name of the child document
  BodyEnfant.replaceText('{1erDuMois}', DateDebutMois);
  BodyEnfant.replaceText('{DernierDuMois}',DateFinMois);
  Enfant.setName('Quittance de loyer - 218 rue de Grenelle - '+DateDebutMois);  

  
//SEND AND EMAIL WITH THE DOCUMENT ATTACHED
  var recipient = 'jean-marie.laly@magicmakers.fr';
  var subject = 'Quittance de loyer - '+TextMois+' - '+Annee;
  var body = 'Bonjour, Veuillez trouver ci-joint la quittance de loyer du mois de '+TextMois;
  var pdf = Enfant.getAs("application/pdf");
  GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {attachments: [pdf],name: ''});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the reason of your issue is because the modified values are not saved. So please convert to the PDF after the document was saved. In order to save the modified values to the document, how about this modification for your script?

Here, only modification part in your script was shown.

#### From :

```
//Get the body of the child document
var BodyEnfant = DocumentApp.openById(Enfant.getId()).getBody();

//Replace date fields of the body by the right dates, and changes the name of the child document
BodyEnfant.replaceText('{1erDuMois}', DateDebutMois);
BodyEnfant.replaceText('{DernierDuMois}',DateFinMois);
Enfant.setName('Quittance de loyer - 218 rue de Grenelle - '+DateDebutMois);
```

#### To :

```
//Get the body of the child document
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(Enfant.getId()); // Modified
var BodyEnfant = doc.getBody(); // Modified

//Replace date fields of the body by the right dates, and changes the name of the child document
BodyEnfant.replaceText('{1erDuMois}', DateDebutMois);
BodyEnfant.replaceText('{DernierDuMois}',DateFinMois);
Enfant.setName('Quittance de loyer - 218 rue de Grenelle - '+DateDebutMois); 

doc.saveAndClose(); // Added
```

#### Reference :

- [saveAndClose()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose)

If this was not what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.